# APIs not returning custom field

Tags: surveymonkey

for our scopes we need to use unique ID generated by us for the answers submitted by users. This is possible by adding "?c=" at the end of the survey link followed by the ID number.

Example Format: http://www.surveymonkey.com/s/XXXXX?c=00001

The terrific problem is that the custom value is not returned anyway via API. It is not added as a property of the Answer object  neither its value replaces somehow the respondant_id property.

We see that you are able to expose that data from your internal endpoints that you use for your proprietary web interface but how to get this data from he outside via API?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call 'get_respondent_list', ensure you pass through 'custom_id' in the list of strings in the 'fields' parameter. This will then be returned in the output with the custom value you entered.

Comment: great this is exactly what I was looking for, it was pretty hidden in the documentation sorry for not noticing it. Thanks!